# Kubuntu 15.04 Installation freezes while running grub-install

Tags: grub2, kubuntu

I've been trying to install an OS on my HP Compaq2025. This is happening with Kubuntu 15.04 for AMD64 as well as Ubuntu 14.04 for AMD64 before I tired it with Ubuntu.

The installation runs properly, but freezes at the exact same spot. The progress bar copies all the files, then begins installing and downloading and configuring, and then right after "Configuring Hardware" when it starts running the grub-install program, it just freezes.

The light on the CD drive stops, the HDD light stays on solid for a few seconds, then turns off. The mouse freezes, any lights on the keyboard turn off, and the only way to get out of it is to hold the power button.

I'm not trying to attempt a dual-boot. I previously used gParted to format the hard drive (NTFS) for a clean install and when I do the installation, I select Kubuntu to use the entire hard drive.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!